# Java syntax for iterating through array of objects like "for (String key : {"key1", "key2"})"

Tags: java, loops

With C++, we can do the following:

```cpp
for (auto key : {"key1", "key2", "key3"}) {
   // use key
}
```

How can I do this in Java?

```java
String[] keys = {"key1", "key2", "key3"}
for (String key : keys) {
   // use key
}
```

Can the items to loop over be declared inside the for loop?

Comment: `for(String key : new String[] { ... })`

Comment: Great thanks, maybe you can add this as the answer so I can close the question?

Comment: `Stream.of("key1", "key2", "key3").forEach(key -> ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
for(String key : new String[] { ... })
```

or, if you're using Java 10 or higher, you can recreate the `auto` keyword by using `var`:

```
for(var key : new String[] { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks for the ``var`` info and the answer.

Comment: Minor addition: `var` exists only from Java 10 onward though

Comment: @NathanEsau You're welcome. Please mark this answer as accepted so the question is acutally closed. ;)

Comment: @QBrute That's correct, thank you for the addition!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use arrays specifically you can also use streams:

```
final Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("item1", "item2");
        stream.forEach(item-> {
            //do what you need here
            System.out.println(item);
        });
```